# NotImplementedError('No Geographic Backend exists for %s' % settings.DATABASE_ENGINE)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to replicate the setting of a website which is already running online (developed by someone else) on my local machine but facing difficulty with the following

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/gis/db/backend/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    raise NotImplementedError('No Geographic Backend exists for %s' % settings.DATABASE_ENGINE)
NotImplementedError: No Geographic Backend exists for dummy
```

I have tried to install the Geos library but I am still facing this problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: what does your database configuration look like in the settings.py file?

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'databasename',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'admin',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '****',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

Comment: you should include the info in the question

Comment: i am using django 1.1.1 version .

Comment: Upgrade your version of django.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a database backend that supports GIS. My suggestion is to go through the [GIS tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) to get you up to speed.